# DW.de-Tweets über „aus Prinzip“ und „im Prinzip“

Tags: difference, preposition, vocabulary

Ich versuche meine Frage auf Deutsch zu stellen, weil ich Deutsch lerne. Bitte korrigieren Sie mich, wenn es Fehler gibt.

Ich habe zwei Tweets auf DW.de über *aus Prinzip* und *im Prinzip* gesehen. Aber ich verstehe nicht ganz, warum die beiden unterschiedliche Antworten haben.

> 1. Ich kaufe ____ kein Tiefkühl-Gemüse. Das soll nicht so gesund sein wie frisches.
>      a) im Prinzip
>      b) aus Prinzip – **richtige Antwort nach der Mehrheit der Antworten (Tweets).**
> 2. Ich kaufe ____ kein Gemüse aus Italien. Aber diese Kirschen haben mich so angelacht …
>      a) im Prinzip – **richtige Antwort nach der Mehrhheit der Antworten (Tweets)**
>      b) aus Prinzip

Comment: Jo, ich habe dir die Fehler größtenteils rauskorrigiert. Mich irritiert noch der erste Teilsatz des zweiten Absatzes: Hast du die Tweets selbst abgeschickt, oder hast du sie nur gesehen? In dem Zusammenhang wäre es gut, wenn du erklärst, was »De.de«- oder »DW.de«-Tweets (Titel und Inhalt widersprechen sich) eigentlich sind? Ich kann mir darunter nichts vorstellen …

Comment: @Jan viel Dank. Ich habe diese tweet auf dem Tweeter gesehen.   https://twitter.com/dw_learngerman/status/594524512621883393    ,  https://twitter.com/dw_learngerman/status/594502118712684544

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Das ist eine sehr schöne Frage, die die Feinheiten der Wortwahl berührt. Wichtig ist hier immer der Kontext, der erst durch den jeweils zweiten Satz hergestellt wird. Wenn man die zweiten Sätze vertauscht, *vertauschen sich auch die Präpositionen*:

> Ich kaufe **im Prinzip** kein Tiefkühl-Obst, aber diese Kirschen haben mich so angelächelt.
>
> Ich kaufe **aus Prinzip** kein Gemüse aus Italien. Das soll nicht so gesund sein wie deutsches.

Die Präposition **aus** verstärkt hier das Prinzip, macht es zu einem Grundsatz oder noch stärker.

> Ich kaufe aus Prinzip nichts mehr von Debitel. (Die haben mich mal übers Ohr gehauen.)
>
> Ich fahre aus Prinzip lieber Bahn. (Autos schaden der Umwelt mehr.)

Die Präposition **im**, hingegen, schwächt das Prinzip ab, lässt einen erwarten, dass es schon im nächsten Satz fallengelassen wird – egal ob aus übergeordneten Gründen oder aus Lust und Laune.

> Im Prinzip fahre ich lieber Bahn. (Jetzt habe ich aber das Auto genommen.)
>
> Im Prinzip esse ich nur Biofleisch. (Aber heute hat ein Döner sein müssen.)

In deinen Beispielen hast du einmal etwas grundlegendes, nämlich das Tiefkühlgemüse weniger Frisch ist. Da muss *aus Prinzip* stehen. Und einmal hast du ein Prinzip, das sofort gebrochen wird. Da muss *im Prinzip* stehen.

---

Einen schönen Zusatzaspekt hat ein Kommentar eben beigetragen:

Das *aus* in *aus Prinzip* impliziert eine Begründung, die im nächsten Satz zu erfolgen hat.

Bei *im Prinzip* hat man keine solche implizite Begründung, im Gegenteil es folgen eher Sätze, die mit *aber* eingeleitet werden.

Comment: Vielleicht noch ein Aspekt wäre, dass die Präposition bei "aus Prinzip" eine *Begründung* impliziert: das Prinzip ist der Grund für das, was im zweiten Satz passiert. Dies ist bei "im Prinzip" nicht der Fall. Hier könnte man noch erwähnen, dass bei dieser Formulierung so gut wie immer ein "aber" folgt - z.B. in Antworten wie "im Prinzip schon, aber".